# nagios check_zypper always returns OK

Tags: nagios

I am trying to use the check_zypper plugin for Nagios (http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_zypper/details), however it always returns:
"Updates OK: no updates available"
even when there are updates available.
Sometimes this message is displayed with status OK, while most of the time it is yellow with status WARNING.

I am using plugin version 1.01 with SLES 11.2

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the version Nagios hosts and suggest on their website is old and outdated. The latest version available from [build.opensuse.org](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=server:monitoring&package=nagios-plugins-zypper) seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that the command or service definition is using a local definition of your check_zypper plugin.
I use the version available from main repos. You can install it with zypper:

```
zypper install nagios-plugins-zypper
```

Or download it from http://software.opensuse.org and install version 1.48, last stable at this moment.